# Does the PayPal API allow you to assign a price based on an algorithm? If so, how?

Tags: api, paypal

I have been reviewing this forum and the documentation for PayPal API but am still uncertain about one thing: Can I have an algorithm determine the price of certain services on a PayPal button (rather than designing a bunch of preset buttons and choosing which one to display)? I would like to have this information feed in from an external database and would appreciate any tips on which lever to pull.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to make sure it's not a hosted button, which would make the amount be included in a hidden field with the form button.  Then you could dynamically adjust the amount based on any logic you want.

The down-side to that is the button isn't as secure because people could view source, copy the HTML, change the amount, and then submit the payment that way.  Of course, there are ways to manage this, but it's something to consider.

Another option would be to use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) instead, in which case it would be completely secure and fully customizable to handle pricing however you need to.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that's very helpful. I'll check out Express Checkout API. Fortunately it's not for a product that ships so if they hack and send us money, we can just adjust the price appropriately. But I can see how that's not quite scalable either. Thanks!